# Trying to calculate mouse x or y (or ratio of both) with given angle to give a distance

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, html5-canvas, trigonometry

I have the xy coordinates from before and during a drag event, `this.x` and ````` this.y```` are the current coordinates, `````this.lastX`and`this.lastY``` are the origin.

What I need to do is given a radian of the source element, determine which mouse coordinate to use, IE if the angle is 0 then the x coordinates is used to give a "distance" if the degrees are 90 then the y coordinates are used

if the radian is 0.785398 then both x and y would need to be used.

I have the following code for one axis, but this only flips the y coordinates

```
        let leftPosition;
        if (this.walls[this.dragItem.wall].angle < Math.PI / 2) {
          leftPosition = Math.round((-(this.y - this.lastY) / this.scale + this.dragItem.origin.left));
        } else {
          leftPosition = Math.round(((this.y - this.lastY) / this.scale + this.dragItem.origin.left));
        }
```

I have an example here https://engine.owuk.co.uk

what I need to do is have the radian dictate what x or y coordinate is used to control the drag of the item by calculating the leftPosition, I have been loosing my mind trying to get this to work :(

Comment: You're going to be doing a lot of Math. What about more complex shapes? Have you considered using a different canvas for each layer? Then you just move the canvas based on x, y.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to make the solution to my issue

```
let position;

const sin = Math.sin(this.walls[this.dragItem.wall].angle);
const cos = Math.cos(this.walls[this.dragItem.wall].angle);

position = Math.round(((this.x - this.lastX) / this.scale * cos + (this.y - this.lastY) / this.scale * sin) + this.dragItem.origin.left);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Math.sin and Math.cos is what you need, here is an example

```html
<canvas id="c" width=300 height=150></canvas>
<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');

  function drawShape(size, angle, numPoints, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (j = 0; j < numPoints; j++) {
      a = angle * Math.PI / 180
      x = size * Math.sin(a)
      y = size * Math.cos(a)
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      angle += 360 / numPoints
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
  }

  ctx.translate(80, 80);
  drawShape(55, 0, 7, "green");
  drawShape(45, 0, 5, "red");
  drawShape(35, 0, 3, "blue");

  ctx.translate(160, 0);
  drawShape(55, 15, 7, "green");
  drawShape(45, 35, 5, "red");
  drawShape(35, 25, 3, "blue");
</script>
```

Comment: yeah that doesn't really answer by question I need the x/y from the mouse given an angle, ive done the cos/sin to get the plot the x/y its the calculating the angle back into the mouse so a drag on x or y is returned right

Comment: its the reverse of what your suggesting, I need to calc the x/y from the mouse not in the canvas I have the canvas element angle I need to calc the mouse x/y usage from  its canvas position to make the drag work

Comment: In your question, you said: `What I need to do is given a radian of the source element, determine which mouse coordinate to use...` on my example, the "element" is always at (0,0) and given the angle I calculate the position ___ If that is not what you need can you provide an image clarifying what you are trying to calculate

Comment: please see below, if you click on the green hightlighted item, I know that I will need to track x and y coordinates of the mouse to drag the item, If you pick the item on wall A I know its only go to be the X coordinates and the walls C and E it would be the Y coordinates, what I

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkCUC.jpg

Comment: Basically I want to calculate a distance the mouse has moved in the angle defined by the wall, that has been defined from the x/y coordinates and converted into a left position

Comment: Its not the distance between two points, lets say the wall is 0 degrees (wall A) to move the item in the wall I know I need to use the x axis mouse position, if the wall angle is 45 degrees I know I need to use the x and y axis of the mouse, if the wall is at 90 degrees then I know its all y, my issue is knowing programatically which mouse axis to track, depending on the wall angle, I need to clamp I either need to use x or y depending on the angle of the wall...

Comment: I have tried 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507849/calculate-the-position-along-a-wall-using-mouse-x-and-y-depending-on-wall-angle

Comment: third attempt to explain 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60514985/calculating-which-mouse-axis-x-or-y-to-track-from-a-given-angle-of-a-draggle-ite

Comment: found the solution took me 4 days

`        let position;

        const sin = Math.sin(this.walls[this.dragItem.wall].angle);
        const cos = Math.cos(this.walls[this.dragItem.wall].angle);

        position = Math.round(((this.x - this.lastX) / this.scale * cos + (this.y - this.lastY) / this.scale * sin) + this.dragItem.origin.left);
`

Comment: Accepting your answer as it did work towards my solution thank you @Helder

Comment: I was playing with something... making objects relative to the mouse but constrain to an angle, maybe it can come handy in your work:
https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvas_follow_mouse.html

Comment: Thanks @Helder that's very useful, I was stuck on my problem for 4 days, not knowing how to ask the right question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a theoretical answer to your problem.

In the simplest way, you have an object within a segment that has to move relative to the position of the mouse, but constrained by the segment's vector.

Here is a visual representation:
[image]
So with the mouse at the red arrow, the blue circle needs to move to the light blue.
***(the shortest distance between a line and a point)***

How do we do that?
Let's add everything we can to that image:
[image]
The segment and the mouse form a triangle and we can calculate the length of all  sides of that triangle.
The distance between two points is an easy Pythagorean calculation:
https://ncalculators.com/geometry/length-between-two-points-calculator.htm

Then we need the height of the triangle where the base is our segment:
https://tutors.com/math-tutors/geometry-help/how-to-find-the-height-of-a-triangle

That will give us the distance from our mouse to the segment, and we do know the angle by adding the angle of the segment + 90 degrees (or PI/2 in radians) that is all that we need to calculate the position of our light blue circle.

Of course, we will need to also add some min/max math to not exceed the boundaries of the segment, but if you made it this far that should be easy pickings.